# google.maps.places.Autocomplete requests Location too many times in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-api

in my website, I have a singn_up-form and use the Google-Api to give the user some suggestions. The API requests the location of the user once in Internet-Explorer. But if I try Firefox, the requests are looped until I click "Standort immer Freigeben" - it means "always accept".

```
function initialize() {
   autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
     { types: ['geocode'] });
}
```

The code is loaded at document.ready and contains more code, but this snippet also reproduces the error.
Does anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
put the apis in your `<head></head>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

put this in your body tag:

```
 <label for="autocomplete">Please Insert an address:</label>
 <br>
 <input id="autocomplete" type="text" size="100">
```

put this in your onload function:

```
var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');    
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

this is my code :

```js
var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');    
new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="autocomplete">Please Insert an address:</label><br>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" size="100">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have kept some onfocus attribute as given in [Google Maps API Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

```
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
```

OR

If you don't require keeping bounds for places suggestions, you may want to remove it

OR

If you need to set bounds for suggestions keep some condition to not call location consent every time, if user gives permission.

Please keep your condition in `geolocate() function`

> Issue is happening only in Mozilla FireFox

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is this:

```
function handlePermission() {
  navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
    if (result.state == 'granted') {
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (result.state == 'prompt') {
      geoBtn.style.display = 'none';
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(revealPosition,positionDenied,geoSettings);
    } else if (result.state == 'denied') {
      geoBtn.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  });
}
```

then put `handlePermission();` after your callback function receives permission